# Preloading a .swf from multiple sources

Tags: flash, actionscript, preloader

i have a rather big (34 MB) Flash CS4 AS3 swf being loaded as a whole into a preloader like

l.load(new URLRequest("[sample.swf](http://okok.elementfx.com/VR)"));

What are my options to minimize loading time? Can i split the swf and load from several servers?

I'm dynamically loading images from the library:

var myBitmapDataObject:myBitmapData = new myBitmapData(100, 100);
var myImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapDataObject);
addChild(myImage);

Right now i'm declaring/referencing every single image in order to get it included in the compiled clip. Does anyone know of a better way? Haven't got round to using Flex yet.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: How many images are you loading? I don't see anything there that should cause the file to be so large.

Comment: Did you load it? It's 704 images.

Comment: Wait was that whole 3D thing 704 images all stitched together? I assumed you would have made that in something like Papervision and just applied a couple images as textures. That's why I didn't think there'd be so many images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is two separate questions, about (a) reducing loading time, and (b) reducing the number of variable declarations you need to make.

-

Regarding (a), reducing loading time, I'd recommend... changing the way you're approaching (b).

-

Regarding (b), is there such a thing as dynamically loading images from the library?  They're all embedded!  And bloating up your SWF.  What I'd do is use a lazier strategy - pull them out of your SWF, and then load each one straight from the server using image loaders.  For info on how to do that, see http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html#includeExamplesSummary

That should trim the size of your SWF and possibly do away with problem (a), although I don't know how much other stuff you have knocking around in there.

As for your problem with having 704 different declarations, one solution could be to rename your images to have a consistent naming convention, i.e. "image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", ..., "imageN.jpg".  You can do so quickly using programs like Applescript on a Mac or Photoshop on Windows.  Once you have done that, you can do something like this:

```
for(var i:int = 1; i <= 704; ++i)
{
 var url:String = "image" + i + ".jpg"; 
 // load the image from this URL
 // addChild(this image)
 // maybe push it onto the end of an array as well, if you need that
}
```